# Remote iOS Simulator for Windows Option Missing?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have been using Xamarin Remote iOS Simulator for Windows with Visual Studio Professional edition. Upon updating to the latest version of Xamarin for Visual Studio, I no longer see the option for remote simulator [as mentioned here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#Remote_iOS_Simulator_Preview)

[Xamarin iOS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyesR.png)

Comment: The Remoted iOS Simulator for Windows [requires a Visual Studio Enterprise license](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/#Download_and_Install).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iOS Simulator is available for [Visual Studio enterprise](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/#Download_and_Install) now.

The preview was available for everyone earlier

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with **screen sharing** using VNC Viewer. It is not for everyone, but I often had to go to mac and back to PC, it is more comfortable for me now. But I am considering to develop native apps, there is so many issues with xamarin and it wastes a lot of time again and again

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this problems is to downgrade your xamarin.
You can be using the *4.2 - Sep 26, 2016* version and the checkbutton still there.

You can do this using this tutorial:
https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-of-xamarin-