# iOS Simulatos is now only to Visual Studio Enterprise?

Tags: xamarin

I was updated my visual studio community with the last stable xamarin version, then the iOS Simulator removed after update.

The iOS Simulatos is now only to Visual Studio Enterprise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote iOS Simulator for Windows Option Missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680996/remote-ios-simulator-for-windows-option-missing)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Remoted IOS Simulator for Windows is only available for Visual Studio Enterprise License.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/